# How to find a point given its distance from two other points?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry

Given the points A and B on a 2D plane, how do I find the coordinates of point C, which is distant l1 from A and l2 from B?

More specifically, how do I do this in C# with Unity (using vectors)?

I've already found an [algebraic method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236211/finding-a-point-a-certain-distance-away-from-2-points) of achieving this, but I have no idea where to start in turning this into working code.

Comment: There may be zero, one, or two such points.

Comment: You can't, at least not without some more information (you need the distance as a vector, not as a scalar). As dasblinkenlight wrote, there is not one answer (mathematically) to this question.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight or infinite if A=B and l1=l2

Answer (score 4):

your points A and B are the centers of 2 circles, your distances l1 and l2 are the radius of these circles:

Determine where two circles intersect in C#:

http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/09/determine-where-two-circles-intersect-in-c/

here you have the code you can copy paste into your project